# Bash script to kill process older than x time - syntax error in expression

Tags: linux, bash, process, centos, centos7

I'm trying to write a script to kill a process by ID if it is older than 5 minutes. I already know the process ID in `$pid`.

```
pid=1234

# 300 seconds = 5min
maximum_runtime=300

process_start_time=`ps -o lstart= -p $pid`
current_time=`date +%s`

let diff=${current_time}-${process_start_time}

if [ $diff -gt $maximum_runtime ]
then
    kill -3 $pid
fi
```

This results in an error:

> ./script.sh: line 9: let: 11:41:01: syntax error in expression (error token is ":41:01")

I used some code from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/181477/how-do-i-kill-processes-older-than-t/538446#538446). Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: You are trying to subtract values like `1563208699` and `Fri Jul 12 12:26:51 2019`, of course here is an error

Answer (score 1):

```
pid=1234

# 300 seconds = 5min
maximum_runtime=300

process_start_time=`ps -o lstart= -p $pid`
current_time=`date` #got the tiem in same format

let diff="$(($(date -d "$current_time" '+%s') - $(date -d "$process_start_time" '+%s')))"
#result for diff in secconds, calculated using date tool

if [ $diff -gt $maximum_runtime ]
then
    kill -3 $pid
fi
```